# Solving the system of n symmetric equations

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the following n symmetric equations. I am attaching the screenshot below. I want to solve the equation number 29 in an article. If you cannot see the screenshot, I am providing the link to the article below. Equation 29 in the article. How can I solve such an equation system in Mathematica?

https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/159841/1/wp1003.pdf

[image: Equation29]

Comment: you can write the linear system as $Ap=b$ where $p$ has components $p_{i}$ and $b$ can be found from your equation. From what i can see from your equation, $A$ can be written as $u I+vJ$ where $u$ and $v$ are constants, $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the matrix with only ones.

Comment: The solution is $p=A^{-1}b$ you can probably calculate $A^{-1}$ in various way but a straight forward way would be to calculate $A^2$ which should be a linear combination of $A$ and I because $J$ is rank one and commutes with $I$ so there should be 2 distinct eigenvalues and so there should exist a degree 2 anhilliting polynomial of $A$. From $A^2=s A+ t I$ you can find $A^{-1}$

Comment: That way you can have a solution for all $n$ instead of using Mathematica's `Solve` function for a specific $n$

Answer (score 1):

This

```
n=3;
eqns=Table[b[i]p[i]==a/(1+s(n-1))-(p[i](1+s(n-2))-
  s Sum[Boole[j!=i]p[j],{j,1,n}])/((1-s)(1+s(n-1))),{i,1,n}];
vars=Table[p[i],{i,1,n}];
sol=Simplify[Solve[eqns,vars]]
```

solves the system in a fraction of a second, returning

```
{{p[1] -> (a*(-1 + (-1 + s)*b[2])*(-1 + (-1 + s)*b[3]))/
   (1 + b[3] + b[2]*(1 + b[3] - s^2*b[3]) + b[1]*(1 + b[3] -
   s^2*b[3] + b[2]*(1 + b[3] + 2*s^3*b[3] - s^2*(1 + 3*b[3])))), 
 p[2] -> (a*(-1 + (-1 + s)*b[1])*(-1 + (-1 + s)*b[3]))/
   (1 + b[3] + b[2]*(1 + b[3] - s^2*b[3]) + b[1]*(1 + b[3] -
   s^2*b[3] + b[2]*(1 + b[3] + 2*s^3*b[3] - s^2*(1 + 3*b[3])))), 
 p[3] -> (a*(-1 + (-1 + s)*b[1])*(-1 + (-1 + s)*b[2]))/
   (1 + b[3] + b[2]*(1 + b[3] - s^2*b[3]) + b[1]*(1 + b[3] -
   s^2*b[3] + b[2]*(1 + b[3] + 2*s^3*b[3] - s^2*(1 + 3*b[3]))))}}
```

If I try to brute force the simplification step

```
simple=Table[Sum[Boole[j!=i]b[j],{j,1,n}]==(n-1)b[i],{i,1,n}];
Simplify[sol,simple]
```

then that returns

```
{{p[1] -> a/(1 + b[3] + 2*s*b[3]),
  p[2] -> a/(1 + b[3] + 2*s*b[3]), 
  p[3] -> a/(1 + b[3] + 2*s*b[3])}}
```

This appears to have been too aggressive and eliminated all the b[1] and b[2] leaving only b[3] in the process.

It might be possible to apply a more restricted simplification to each of the three parts of the solution such that it would only eliminate the desired b[i] in the process. I'll fiddle a little more with this and see if I can find a compact way to produce the desired simplification.

Comment: In the RHS of the equations, for the denominator of the second term you have `(1 - a)` where eqn (29) has `(1 - s)`

Comment: Thank you for catching my mistake. I hope I've corrected that now.

Comment: Cross posted https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2987550